# How to use TOKENS with ssh LocalForward directive?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

With the following `ssh_config`:

```
Match all
  IdentityFile /opt/ssh/id_rsa
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  ServerAliveInterval 30
  ServerAliveCountMax 3
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPersist 300
  StreamLocalBindMask 0111
  StreamLocalBindUnlink yes
  ExitOnForwardFailure yes
  Compression yes
  BatchMode yes

Host example
  LocalForward /opt/ssh/soc/%n_mysql.socket 127.0.0.1:3306
  ControlPath /opt/ssh/soc/%n.socket
  HostName example.com
  User user
  Port 22
```

Two `unix-socket` files are created:

```
# ls -1 /opt/ssh/soc
example.socket
%n_mysql.socket
```

Obviously `LocalForward` directive doesn't like tokens...

I wonder why and is there an alternative way to achieve this?

I see that `LocalCommand` accepts the following tokens: `%%`, `%C`, `%d`, `%h`, `%i`, `%l`, `%n`, `%p`, `%r`, `%T`, and `%u`. Could it be somehow used to achieve what I want?

I tried the following config, but it only creates the `ctrl` socket, not the `mysql` one.

```
Host example
  PermitLocalCommand yes
  LocalCommand ssh -F /opt/ssh/config -S /opt/ssh/sockets/%n.socket -TNL /opt/ssh/sockets/%n_mysql.socket:127.0.0.1:3306 -p %p -l %u %h
  ControlPath /opt/ssh/soc/%n.socket
  HostName example.com
  User user
  Port 22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my experiments it seems that `openssh` people have decided to make the matters rather complicated. The following wrapper script may provide some inspiration:

```
#! /bin/sh --

HNAME=${1:?## Err: Please specify the host name}

CONFD="/opt/ssh"
SOCKETS="${CONFD}/soc"

ssh -fTNF "${CONFD}/config" "${HNAME}" && {
  ssh -O forward -S "${SOCKETS}/${HNAME}.socket" -TNL "${SOCKETS}/${HNAME}_mysql.socket:127.0.0.1:3306" "${HNAME}" &&\
  ssh -O check -S "${SOCKETS}/${HNAME}.socket" "${HNAME}"
} || exit 1
```